# Acronyms in Label

Tags: labels, acronyms

Is it possible to use `\ac{}` within `\label{}` like `\label{\ac{ex_ac} Algorithm}`. I used it and the compiler disrupted the alignment of the whole document. Apart from that the error line was shown to be the starting of output i.e. the place where `\chapter{}` is used for the first time, irrespective of where I use `\label{\ac{ex_ac} Algorithm}`

I am using OpenLeaf with pdfLaTeX compiler.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. A question: *Why* are you trying to insert an `\ac` instruction inside a `\label` instruction? What are you trying to achieve? (The answer to your question is, "no".)

Comment: Why would you want to use an acronym inside of a label? A label is never printed.

Comment: Well... it's not a necessary. It just occurred to me. I had made an `\acro` and was defining the algorithm about it in a section. Naturally I used `\label` for the section, then I though maybe I can put the `\ac{}` within the label (not a necessary, I know), and the compiler went haywire.

Comment: If it weren't for fear of hurting your feelings, I would tag the question `bad-idea`. :-)

Comment: No problem :). `Bad-ideas` are how people come with great ideas of new features.